# data modelling of land vs owner vs type of ownership.? Please comment

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, data-modeling, relational-model

I have just stared to learn data modelling and would like your views about the way that I have designed my logical model and physical model.

The problem.
1) A person can own multiple land parcels.
2) A land parcel can be owned by multiple persons
3) Persons can have various types of ownership with land parcels

```
 ---------       Owner       ---------
|   Land  |<--------------->|  Person |
 ---------    Owned by       ---------
      |                          | 
      V                          V
   ----------------------------------
  | Ownership Type (sole/joint )     |
   ----------------------------------
```

**Land  Schema**

```
----------------------------------------
Plot no:       |  Area sq.meters
----------------------------------------
A1             |  100
A2             |  200
```

**Person Schema**

```
----------------------------------------
Person Id   |  Name
----------------------------------------
1              |  Tom
2              |  Harry
3              |  Jones
```

**Ownership Type Schema (sole/joint )**

```
----------------------------------------
Type            | Description<br>
----------------------------------------
Sole            | Single owner<br>
Joint - 1       | Joint owner ( first name in the sale deed)
Joint - 2       | Joint owner ( 2nd name in the sale deed)
Joint - 3       | Joint owner ( 3rd name in the sale deed)
```

**Person_Land_Ownership Schema**

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Peson Id      | Plot no:      |  Ownership Type
-------------------------------------------------------
1             |  A1           | Sole       
2             |  A2           | Joint - 1 
3             |  A2           | Joint - 2
```

Please provide opinion/critisim/suggestion on the above modelling approach.

Comment: 1. Your diagram and tables are not consistent. 2. We can't really critique this unless we know the problem statement & assumptions including the method/tool/text you are to model to.

Answer (score 0):

Use abstraction. An individual extends abstract legal party. So does an organization.

Individual : Party

Organization : Party

Asset belongs to Party

Party has many Assets